# Can we always define a congruence category?

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

In Awodey's Category Theory the congruence category is defined as follows...

We have a congruence ~ on a category $C$. Then $C^\tilde{}$ is defined as:

$(C^\tilde{})_0=C_0$

$(C^\tilde{})_1=\{ \left<f,g\right>,f $~$ g \}$

$\tilde{1}_C=\left<1_C,1_C\right>$

$\left<f^\prime,g^\prime\right>\circ\left<f,g\right>=\left<f^\prime f,g^\prime g\right>$

Now what bothers me is that in general we may not have products in the category $C$, but the definition uses products of the form $A\times A$, where $A\in C_0$ (as far as I understood).

Any clarifications will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you are concerned about the use of pairs $\langle f, g \rangle$, which you are thinking of as the product of those morphisms, when the category may not have products.

This is simply confusion caused by a clash of notation. The product of morphisms may not exist in the categorical sense, but Awodey is assuming that the category is locally small, so each collection of morphisms is a set, and one can always take the product of two sets. Here $\langle f, g \rangle$ just means a pair of morphisms, and $\{ \langle f, g \rangle | f \sim g \}$ means the set of all pairs of morhisms $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ is equivalent to $g$.

Comment: I've also thought about this, but since the set of objects of the congruence category is the same as that of $C$, what will the domain and codomain of $\left<f,g\right>$ be? I mean there need not be an object $A\times A$ in $C$.

Comment: @batboio For $f$ and $g$ to be equivalent modulo $\sim$, they have to have the same domain and codomain (by definition of a congruence relation), so the domain and codomain of $\langle f,g \rangle$ in $\mathbf C^\sim$ are the domain and codomain of $f$ (equivalently $g$) in $\mathbf C$

Comment: Since $f$ and $g$ are equivalent, they have the same domain and codomain, say $f, g \colon A \rightarrow B$. The morphism $\langle f, g \rangle$ is now defined to have domain $A$ and codomain $B$ as well. 
Note that $\langle f, g \rangle $ is not literally a pair of morphisms: we are using a pair of equivalent morphisms to describe a morphism in the congruence category.